# user_id is nil when I attempt to create items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm fairly new to Rails and I have an issue where I'm attempting to create items but every item I create has a `user_id` of `nil`. If I create the item within localhost and check to make sure it's created in rails console, it shows but with `user_id = nil`. Thanks in advance for the help!

Users are created using **Devise**.

**Items Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.user = current_user
    if @item.save
      @item = Item.update_items(params[:items])
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Item was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating item. Please try again."
      render @user
    end
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

**Users Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @item = Item.new
    @items = @user.items
  end
end
```

Comment: for this line `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` is that supposed to be whom ever is logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the authenticate before_filter which wasn't allowing the user_id to be assigned....stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = current_user
    @item = current_user.items.new(params[:items])
    if @item.save
      redirect_to current_user, notice: "Item was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating item. Please try again."
      render @user
    end
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

make sure that you have a proper association in your model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  ...
end
```